# How to upgrade mono on openSuse

Tags: linux, opensuse, mono, software-installation

I have a virtual machine running of openSuse 11.2 that has mono 2.6.4, I use this VM as a test server to test asp.net applications under Apache mod_mono.

I wanted to upgrade (in the same virtual machine) to mono 2.8.2. I downloaded several rpm files from http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/openSUSE_11.2/i586/ but I'm in a dependency "loop", don't know which package to install in the correct order...

(Did I mention that I know very little of suse?)

Edit: Is it possible to find a way to upgrade it without network connectivity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [this page](http://software.opensuse.org/package/mono-complete) at opensuse.org and click "1-Click Install" button on `mono-complete-2.8.2` meta package. Then all your loop dependencies will be solved automatically by YaST manager.

It is a usual user-friendly way to install packages on openSuSE.

Comment: This is only user-friendly if you have a GUI installed :)

Comment: Is it possible to do it without internet connection? the VM is only connected to the host machine (windows)

Comment: @jorgebg - Try to download all packages from .../mono/.../openSUSE_11.2/i586/ to a local directory on your VM, go to this directory and run `rpm -U *.rpm`

Comment: Depending on the virtualization software you use, it is possible to allow the VM to also use the same internet connection (if your host machine has internet).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `yast` (interactive) or `zypper` to directly update software from a repository. This will avoid any dependency problems.

```
zypper ref -f
zypper up [package]
```

This refreshes the repository and then updates the system. Adding a package after the `update` (`up`) command is optional and can be used to only update a specific one.